# Location of a new electrical sub panel

Tags: electrical

I am installing a 125A sub panel (fed with 60A breaker from main panel). Am I allowed to install it directly below the existing panel? Are there minimum height requirements for a sub panel? Is there a minimum distance between sub panels?

Comment: How much space do you *have* from the bottom of the existing panel to the floor?  Also, do you already have the subpanel you plan to install, or have you not picked it out yet?

Comment: I have about 4 feet from the bottom of the existing panel to the floor (I can measure exactly later if needed). I am planning to buy the Eaton BRP12L125G to tie into my existing Cutler Hammer panel.

Comment: Is the existing panel flush mounted into the wall or surface mounted to an unfinished wall? Also, what's the amp rating of the existing main panel?

Answer (score 2):

There is no minimum mounting height for electrical panels.

There's also no minimum space between panels.  However you do have to provide enough space that the covers don't interfere with each other.

Comment: I might add that the sub-panel must be protected from damage. In this case we are talking about water damage. There is no minimum but I would recommend about 18" to the bottom of the lowest breaker if possible.

Answer (score 2):

### Go BIG or go home!

There is literally *no* reason to restrict yourself to a puny 12-space panel for your subpanel here, given that you have ample vertical room for more.  A BRP24L125G is a mere $30 costlier (if that) than the BRP12L125G you were originally going to use, and provides twice as many full-sized spaces for the price, a bargain considering the costs of having to go back and *repeat* this exercise, especially if the panels involved are flush-mounted.

If you want to go bigger yet, the BRP40L200G provides even more space for a mere $60-$70 more than the BRP12L125G; it also can take full advantage of a 200A feeder if you have a 200A service to your main panel, allowing you to use a *sub-feed lug* block in the main panel instead of a separate breaker dedicated to the feeder.

### About that feeder...

There are very few reasons to limit yourself to a 60A feeder for a panel right next door to your existing panel, and I bet none of them apply here.  So, I would upsize the feeder to 125A at a *minimum*, using a 125A breaker (for a service >125A) or a set of 125A *subfeed lug* blocks (for a service <=125A), with 1/0 Al XHHW-2 single conductors (hot, hot, neutral) in a 2" rigid nipple with grounding locknuts (as bonding around concentric/eccentric KOs is not needed for non-service applications <250V) and insulating bushings (to protect the wires from abrasion).

If you have a 200A service and are putting in a 200A subpanel, then there's very little reason not to upsize further; that 2" nipple will happily handle 3 250kcmil Al XHHW-2 singles, which is enough for a full 200A feeder off of a 225A subfeed lug block in the main panel.  In either case, since the feeder wires are larger than 4AWG, we're free to remark conductors here, allowing you to buy a single long length of wire, cut it into thirds, and phase-tape it yourself.

### To answer your questions on location...

The good news is that yes, you can use the space below your existing panel for your new subpanel; there is no minimum height requirement for panels or breakers in the NEC, and the only limits on how close together the two panels can be are set by any wiring coming out the bottom of the existing panel (or that needs to be routed out the top of the new panel, as right-angle NM connectors/clamps aren't a thing), and the need to accommodate the flanges on the panel covers so they don't overlap (unless you wish to do sheet-metal work on them, that is).  However, it's a good idea to keep the bottom of the busbars about 12-18" off the ground to prevent a minor flood from trashing the subpanel.

### TORQUE ALL LUGS TO SPEC

There is one more thing you need to pay attention to with this job, and that is the new Code requirement (added in 2017) in NEC 110.14(D) that the mechanical lugs used on distribution equipment *must* be torqued to their specification torque (labeled on the breaker or loadcenter) using an (inch-pound, as that's what the torques are specified in) torque wrench or torque screwdriver.  Even if your locality has not adopted the 2017 NEC, this is still a good idea, lest your electrical system [lose you the race!](https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/features/the-difference-between-success-and-failure-how-a-torque-wrench-improves-system-reliability/)